# Different behavior of setlength and settowidth

Tags: spacing, lengths

In this example, I would expect all "MMM" to be well-aligned to each other. But they aren't:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\newcommand{\before}{mmm}%
\newcommand{\after}{MMM}%
\newlength{\myplus}%
\begin{document}%
\begin{multline}%
\settowidth{\myplus}{\before}%
\the\myplus\hfill\\%
\before,\after\hfill\\%
%
\hspace{\myplus},\after\hfill\\%
\hspace*{\myplus},\after\hfill\\%
%
\setlength{\myplus}{25pt}%
\hspace{\myplus},\after\hfill\\%
\hspace*{\myplus},\after\hfill\\%
%
\hspace{25pt},\after\hfill\\%
\hspace*{25pt},\after\hfill\\%
\end{multline}%
\end{document}
```

In particular, `\mylength` and `25pt` behave differently even after `\setlength{\myplus}{25pt}`. Also, `settowidth` sets the width to `25pt`, but `\myplus` acts even different after that.

Why is that, and how can I achieve spacing in combination with `setlength`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the length in a local group, so it is 0pt again on the following line, also you have set it to the width of `mmm` in the text font, but show it set in math italic,

perhaps you want

```
\settowidth{\myplus}{$\before$}%
```

outside (before) the `multline`, depending on your real use case.

Comment: For the second part of your question, I actually use `\ensuremath` in my document to have the correct font, but yes, I need to check whether this is correct. I could not do so yet because it was never really working as intended. Now, I really want the `\setlength` in the `multline` environment without repeating `setlength` before every line where I use it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @bers why are you needing to do this at all rather than use an alignment environment like `align`? but anyway you can use `\settowidth\myplus{....}global\myplus=\myplus` to make it global (not the most efficient but unless you are doing thousands of them that probably doesn't matter) doing the setting inside the ams environment is already inefficient as they set everything twice so they can measure

Comment: @bers `\ensurmath` isn't really needed inside `\settotwidth` that content is never in math mode so the test `\ensuremath` does is rather pointless, it will always add `$`.

Comment: Thank you! Your last comment raises another question that I will ask separately.